# WPF add columns dynamically to datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which has binding to a datatable's defaultview. I need this binding since the columns are not fixed, but I need to have 2 fixed columns at the end of the datagrid which have an image button in every cell to display certain properties of each row, or to allow users to delete a row.

How can I add those 2 fixed columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do following I think,

```
    MyDataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += OnAutoGeneratedColumns;

    private void OnAutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myImageTemplate = TryFindResource("MyImageTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        if (myImageTemplate != null)
        {
            MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                Header = "Delete",
                CellTemplate = myImageTemplate
            });
        }
    }
```

In the xaml,

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```